# iCloud switch on/off error

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, icloud, sigkill

Testing on iPhone 6 device (not simulator); iOS Version 9.2.1

I am following Apple's iCloud Design Guide and implemented the first chapter "[iCloud Fundamentals (Key-Value and Document Storage)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW1)."

If I am logged into iCloud and then I sign out of iCloud, my app crashes and all I get is a "Thread 1: signal SIGKILL." 
[image]

Is the crashing supposed to occur? Or do I need to fix this somehow? The Apple iCloud Design Guide does not mention this (at leas I don't see it).

My eventual goal is to have iCloud Core Data sync. Right now the only code I have is the one from the first chapter of Apple's docs from the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. iOS will kill any app using the current iCloud account if the user logs out of iCloud on the iOS device.

This is similar to iOS killing apps when certain privacy settings change.

Comment: Thanks!! So how will I handle this when the user comes back to the app. The app crashed and now what is the recommended steps to take? Maybe Apple's iCloud Design Guide has this answer, just haven't read that far possibly.

Comment: I will accept the answer, but it says I have to wait 7 minutes.

Comment: The app didn't crash. iOS killed it. Your app needs to do what it should already be doing - it should be checking the status of iCloud. The user can log out. The user can log into a different account. Your app needs to handle these cases every time it runs, not just after iOS kills the app because the user logged out. Also deal with the user logging into an iCloud account why your app is running.